# date interval from sybase to oracle

Tags: oracle, database-migration, sybase

hi guys a need your help, I'm migrating some stored procedures from sybase to oracle, and I don't know how to transform this line to oracle.

```
select @date_vig_aux = dateadd(ss,-1,@date_vig_aux)
```

I would appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing date_vig_aux is defined as DATE or TIMESTAMP in pl/sql, this should translate into

```
date_vig_aux:=date_vig_aux+numtodsinterval(-1,'second');
```